# Global access to some component in Phalcon

Tags: php, registry, global, phalcon

How can I make some classes and objects accessible from all MVC layers?

For example I want to access to current user's profile and `config.ini` file globally.

In Zend Framework 1.x I was using Zend_Registery for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [DI container](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html) for this.

A simple way to access your config is to create a lambda function in your bootstrap like so:

```
$configFile  = require(ROOT_PATH . '/web/config/global.php');

// Create the new object
$config = new \Phalcon\Config($configFile);

// Store it in the Di container
$this->di['config'] = $config;
```

Accessing this object from a controller is as simple as:

```
$config = $this->config;
```

From any other part of your application, you can always grab the Di container and access it from there like so:

```
$di = \Phalcon\DI\FactoryDefault::getDefault();
$config = $di->config;
```

Have a look at a bootstrap example [here](https://github.com/phalcon/website/blob/master/app/library/Ph/Bootstrap.php). It showcases how services are registered in the Di container.

As per the current users profile, you can always use the Session component to store that information and retrieve it at will in the same manner as the config above.

Finally you can register your own Registry service in Phalcon. I have an example [here](https://gist.github.com/niden/3033673) if you are interested.

Comment: After user logs in, I want make its profile accessible in all layers. If I store it in `session` its will not updated if user profiles changes during the session.

Answer (score 1):

I built an extended skeleton for some phalcon issues.  This was one of them.

Checkout the project here: https://github.com/alanbarber111/cloud-phalcon-skeleton

But, basically `Cloud::app()->getPhalconDi()` or `Cloud::app()->getPhalconRouter()` or `Cloud::app()->getPhalconApplication()` can be called from anywhere in the app

Answer (score 0):

It's worth mentioning that Phalcon includes a built in registry service which I found helpful:

https://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Registry.html